# Semi-elliptic pdes reference

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, textbook-recommendation

The pde

$$ Pf(x)=\sum _{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}(x){\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x_{i}\,\partial x_{j}}}(x)+\sum _{i=1}^{n}b_{i}(x){\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_{i}}}(x)+c(x)f(x),$$
is said to be [semi-elliptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-elliptic_operator) when the matrix $(a_{ij}(x))$ is *positive semidefinite* for all x.

> Q1: What are some comprehensive references on them?

They are not treated in Evans, and the reference in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-elliptic_operator) is Oksendal's SPDEs book, which actually looks at the case $c\equiv 0$ and doesn't cover the same results as Evans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have guessed that many do not pass through. One of the most basic things fails because for a divergence form operator $D_i(a_{ij}(x)D_ju)$ you do not have
$$
\int |Du|^2 \leq \int a_{ij}D_iuD_ju
$$
which is the basis of an energy estimate.